# Refreshing Data in a fragment using FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have three fragments in my Pager and i am adding some strings using Bundle 
 while instantiating each fragment in my adapter. I am using these strings to filter out the data that i am fetching from database.I tried simply notifydatasetchanged() method but its not working also i tried instantiating the adapter seprately inside the querysubmit() method below that didnt work as well. I couldnt find any solution where someone is passing information to fragments through the adapter to refresh them.

so basically this is what i am doing

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 // some code here basically variables 
// filterString is what i am passing to adapter to filter data 

pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.Projectviewpager);
adapter = new 
ProjectTabsAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),filterString,getContext());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager);

// This is where i want to send string to refresh the fragment in pager.


searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new 
MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        filterString = query;

        // i want to send the string to fragment here 
        }
    }
```

My Adapter

```
public class ProjectTabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private Context mContext ;
private String mSkill;

private String tabTitles[] = new String[]{"tab1", "tab2
", "tab3"};
public ProjectTabsAdapter( FragmentManager fm,String skill,Context 
context) {
    super(fm);

    mSkill = skill;
    mContext= context;
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // sending bundle to each fragment

    if (position == 0) {

        Tab1 fragment = new Tab1();

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Filter String"+ mSkill, 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putString("skill_set", mSkill);

        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;

    } else if (position == 1){
        return new tab2();
    } else if (position == 2){
        return new tab3();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}



public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabTitles[position];
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define public refresh methods in both the adapter and the Tab:

```
public class ProjectTabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private Context mContext ;
private String mSkill;
private Tab1 fragment;

private String tabTitles[] = new String[]{"tab1", "tab2
", "tab3"};
public ProjectTabsAdapter( FragmentManager fm,String skill,Context 
context) {
    super(fm);

    mSkill = skill;
    mContext= context;
}

public void refreshTab1(String skill) {
fragment.refreshSkill(skill); //define public void refreshSkill(String skill) in the Tab1 fragment
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // sending bundle to each fragment

    if (position == 0) {

        fragment = new Tab1();

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Filter String"+ mSkill, 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putString("skill_set", mSkill);

        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;

    } else if (position == 1){
        return new tab2();
    } else if (position == 2){
        return new tab3();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}



public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabTitles[position];
}


}
```

Then in your listener call the refresh method:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new 
MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        filterString = query;

        // i want to send the string to fragment here 
        adapter.refreshTab1(filterString);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey i am sorry for asking this again , but i am facing a weird issue with the solution above it worked for me when i refresh one fragment alone but when i refresh three fragments it is now showing call refreshTab on a null object reference error. its actually weird because i am refreshing two other fragments the same way but they are not showing any such error but only one of the fragment.

Comment: Are you updating the 3 in bulk or are you checking which tab you are on? because if in bulk, a tab might haven't been initialized, or it might have been destroyed. If updating in bulk add a null check like this:


`public void refreshTab1(String skill) {
if(fragment != null) {
   fragment.refreshSkill(skill);
}
}`

Comment: i tried the same thing earlier but somehow only one of the fragment is null others are working fine